# Firefox context menu item icon

Tags: firefox-addon, stylesheet, xul

I am trying to add an icon in context menu but don't know why it is not showing.

Here is the complete code:

**chrome.menifest**

```
content   xulschoolhello              jar:chrome/xulschoolhello.jar!/content/
skin      xulschoolhello  classic/1.0 jar:chrome/xulschoolhello.jar!/skin/
locale    xulschoolhello  en-US       jar:chrome/xulschoolhello.jar!/locale/en-US/

overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul  chrome://xulschoolhello/content/browserOverlay.xul

style   chrome://browser/content/browser.xul  chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/browserOverlay.css
```

**browserOverlay.xul**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM
  "chrome://xulschoolhello/locale/browserOverlay.dtd">

<overlay id="xulschoolhello-browser-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  .
  .
  .

  <!-- Context menu additions -->
  <popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
      <menuseparator id="ss-context-menu-separator"/>
      <menuitem id="ss-context-menu-item" class="menuitem-iconic"
                label="click me"
                oncommand="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.sayHello(event);"/>
  </popup>
</overlay>
```

**browserOverlay.css**

```
#ss-context-menu-item {
  list-style-image: url("ss_16.png");
}
```

Any idea about problem?

Comment: First thing to test: does that image load at all? Try opening `chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/ss_16.png` in browser.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant: I posted the whole code because may be some other thing causing the problem. Anyway reduced the code. chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/ss_16.png is opening in the brwoser.

Comment: Shouldn't the file be called chrome.manifest? (not menifest)

Answer (score 0):

From my tests with my own extension, I think that maybe you have to add a reference to the stylesheet in the overlay, in addition to the one in `chrome.manifest`. To do this you have to add the following line before the doctype declaration:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/browserOverlay.css" type="text/css"?>
```

If you don't put the file name, leaving only `chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/`, it should also work, according to the [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Adding_Style_Sheets).

Comment: already checked, no effect. css and image files are in same directory so no need to use the full path.

Comment: Ok. Are you referencing browserOverlay.css in the overlay? It isn't in your snippet.

Comment: You are wrong - URLs in CSS files are always relative to the CSS file location. So using a full URL is unnecessary. And `browserOverlay.css` is referenced in `chrome.manifest` (it is a style overlay).

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The stylesheet is indeed referenced in the last line of `chrome.manifest`.

Comment: I've now had the oportunity to do some tests with my own extension and I think that you have to link to the stylesheet from the overlay, in addition to the reference in `chrome.manifest`. I will edit my answer to give more details.

Comment: @Woundorf: still no effect. other css styles are working like color:green will change the menuitem label color to green.

Comment: Well, then I have no clue what it may be :(